# Trying to rotate application in reverse portrait but its not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

> Trying to rotate application in portrait/landscape/reverse
>   portrait/reverse landscape. its rotating app in only three mode but
>   unable to rotate application in reverse portrait.
>
> My code:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (isRecording == false) {
            Log.v("new orientation", "yes");
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                wholeView.setOrientation(1);
            }
            else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                wholeView.setOrientation(0);
            }else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                wholeView.setOrientation(0);
            }else if (newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT)
            {

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                wholeView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            }
```